# php array_diff compare arrays with new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$userBuildingIds
```

print_r():

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
 )
```

and `$allRequiredIds`

print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 1
)
```

now I want check if one element of $userBuildingIds exists in 
the $allRequiredIds array. And if so, I want get a new array of all elements they are NOT in the first array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

(because 1 isn't in $userBuildingIds)
I try this with `array_diff` but it gives me this result (with the key of array 2):

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
)
```

Is it possible to get an array in which are all the elements of array `$allRequiredIds` where are not in `$userBuildingIds`, but without copy the keys from  `$allRequiredIds`?

Comment: If you don't care about the keys of the returned array then you can just use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on it to get a new array having the keys starting with `0`. So, the complete code will be `array_values(array_diff($allRequiredIds, $userBuildingIds))`.

Comment: thanks, this will work.. you can answer this, so I can accept your answer.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achive and how different values could be in your array. but I am sure you know that for `$arr1 = [1,1,1,1,1];
$arr2 = [1,2]; array_diff($arr1, $arr2);` will return emty array? that is really your point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the keys of the returned array then you can just use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on it to get a new array having the keys starting with `0`.

The code will be:

```
$diffIds = array_values(array_diff($allRequiredIds, $userBuildingIds));
```

It produces a list of values from `$allRequiredIds` that does not exist in `$userBuildingIds`. The returned list has numeric keys starting with `0` (no association with the original keys from `$allRequiredIds` is `$userBuildingIds` is kept, on purpose).